# If else with && statement not working inside SensorManager

Tags: android, countdowntimer, sensormanager

I want to start `CountDownTimer` if my altitude is changing to outside the range of values I set using barometer.

So for example if the value is > 40 and < 43, there is no action
If the value is < 41 and > 42 , the countdowntimer will start ticking.
But if the value return into inside of 41-42 then the timer will stop ticking and so on.

Here's my code:

```
public SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float pressure_value = 0.0f;
        float height = 0.0f;
        if (Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE == event.sensor.getType())
        {
            pressure_value = event.values[0];
            height = SensorManager.getAltitude(1009,pressure_value);
        }
        value = String.valueOf(height);
        txtBaro.setText(value);
        valueOftxtBaro = Float.parseFloat(value);
        if (valueOftxtBaro < 41 && valueOftxtBaro > 42)
        {
            actCountDownTimer();
        }
        else if (valueOftxtBaro < 43 && valueOftxtBaro > 40 )
        {
            cdt.cancel();    <------------------Here is line 202------------>
            txtTest.setText("Paused");
        }
        else
        {
            txtTest.setText("Null");
        }

    }
```

This is the `CountDownTimer` code:

```
public void actCountDownTimer ()
    {
        cdt = new CountDownTimer(total,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                total = millisUntilFinished;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
```

When I run this code I get an error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.CountDownTimer.cancel()' on a null object reference
            at skripsi.ubm.studenttracking.indoor$3.onSensorChanged(indoor.java:202)
            }.start();
        }
```

Could you help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If your valueOftxtBaro is > 40 and < 43 at the very first time your onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) method is called by the listener, it will call cdt.cancel(), although cdt has not been initialized (it is only in the upper branch). Try that instead :

```
public SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float pressure_value = 0.0f;
        float height = 0.0f;
        if (Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE == event.sensor.getType())
        {
            pressure_value = event.values[0];
            height = SensorManager.getAltitude(1009,pressure_value);
        }
        value = String.valueOf(height);
        txtBaro.setText(value);
        valueOftxtBaro = Float.parseFloat(value);
        if (valueOftxtBaro < 41 && valueOftxtBaro > 42)
        {
            actCountDownTimer();
        }
        else if (valueOftxtBaro < 43 && valueOftxtBaro > 40 )
        {
            if (cdt != null)
                cdt.cancel();

            txtTest.setText("Paused");
        }
        else
        {
            txtTest.setText("Null");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
valueOftxtBaro = Float.parseFloat(value);
            if (valueOftxtBaro < 41 && valueOftxtBaro > 42){
```

The condition `valueOftxtBaro < 41 && valueOftxtBaro > 42` is always false - valueOftxtBaro can not be < 41 and > 42 at the same time.

Also, like Dimitri shows, add a null check for `cdt` before calling the cancel method.

Edit:

Even with the above fixed, your code would create a new CountDownTimer every time the first if condition is true. You should create a new timer only if it hasn't been created yet. Try something like this that should have all the above fixed:

```
if (valueOftxtBaro < 41 || valueOftxtBaro > 42) { // baro outside range [41, 42]
    if (cdt == null) {
        cdt = new CountDownTimer(total, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                total = millisUntilFinished;
            }
        };
        cdt.start();
    }
} else { // baro inside range  [41, 42]
    if (cdt != null) {
        cdt.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have write like your code and dimitri code. For the first time it work perfectly. But when the condition return false, the countdowntimer is start ticking and then when the value return true the countdowntimer is still ticking. How it gonna supposed to do ?

Comment: if valueoftxtbaro < 42 || valueoftxtbaro >43 { actCountDownTimer();}
else if (valueoftxtbaro < 44 || valueoftxtbaro > 41)
{ if (cdt!= null)
   { cdt.cancel(); } }

Comment: Still not working even i already put .start(); in the timer. For the first, it is working perfectly. But when the value is outside of range again, the countdowntimer is not ticking

Comment: Added a call to cdt.start() to the example code. Note, that the baro needs to remain outside the range for 1 second, or nothing happens. Try lowering the interval from 1000 to say 50 and add some logging into the onTick method to see if it ever gets called.